# Python - Array won't shuffle and print

Tags: python, arrays, shuffle

```
import random 

def shuffle(ary):

    ary = [1,2,3,4,5]
    d=len[ary]
    b=d-1
    while (d > 0):
        x=random.randint(0,d)
        if x == d: 
            ary[b],ary[x]=ary[x],ary[d]
    return ary

print("shuffle list" + str(shuffle(ary)))
```

Comment: you have quiet a bit going on here that needs to be fixed, but for starters, you are attempting to pass a variable that you defined in your function into your function

Comment: your while loop never exits, you have while `d > 0` when will `d` not be greater than 0?

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone through your logic. Just corrected your code syntactically. You had passed the list without initializing it. Had created an infinite loop( never decremented the param d)

```
import random 
ary = [1,2,3,4,5]

def shuffle(ary):
    d=len(ary)
    b=d-1
    while (d > 0):
        x=random.randint(0,b)
        if x == d: 
            ary[b],ary[x]=ary[x],ary[d]
        d=d-1
    return ary

print("shuffle list" + str(shuffle(ary)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**FYI** there's a predefined [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function in the random package

```
import random
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
random.shuffle(array) # shuffles in place
print("My shuffled list", array)
```

For your case, you need to define the array, before passing it to the function

```
ary = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(shuffle(ary))
```

Comment: that gives me the error                                                                                    
     TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: using the standard function or yours ?

Answer (score 1):

You have quiet a few errors, I worked them out for you and I'll break it down currently working on explanation to all parts of where you went wrong.

```
import random 

def shuffle(some_ary, mixes): 
    d = len(some_ary) - 1
    for i in range(mixes): 
        x = random.randint(0, d)
        y = random.randint(0, d)
        while y == x:
            y = random.randint(0, d)
        some_ary[x], some_ary[y] = some_ary[y], some_ary[x]
    return some_ary

ary = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(f"Shuffle: {shuffle(ary, 10)}")
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 shuffle.py 
> Shuffle: [5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
> ```

First thing first:

```
def shuffle(ary):

    ary = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

You are decalring `ary` inside the function we need to move that outside so we can pass it into the function using `suffle(ary)`

```
d=len[ary]
b=d-1
```

This should be one line `d = len[ary] - 1`

```
while (d > 0):
```

Now the good stuff :) First we have `while(d > 0)`, if you want to use this we have to add something that eventually end this loop so after each run lets add in a `d -= 1`, but even so you should be using a `for loop` instead which would be `for i in range(mixes)` no need to use `d` here since the amount of cycles is really up to you, the higher you go the more randomization we will get. In this example lets pass `mixes` along with our array.

Next our Shuffling:

```
    x=random.randint(0,d)
```

In context of your code this would have been a random between `0` and `5`, since `lists` start at a `0` index your current `ary` has indexes from `0-4`
so we want a random int in that range, in your code this would have been `b` since `b` was `d - 1`.

```
if x == d:
```

This if says that `if the random int == 5` which is out of the range of indexes, lets though for the sake of it assume you meant `4`, all this would do only ever give us a index of `4` which isn't what we want for shuffling we want a random index throughout so lets get rid of that.

Lets instead grab another random variable to swap with so we always swap two random numbers

```
y = random.randint(0, b)
while y == x:
    y = random.randint(0, b)
```

Here we generate another random number for an index but also make sure its not equal to the one we are swapping with

And finally we swap:

```
ary[b],ary[x]=ary[x],ary[d]
```

Again if we use this method we would only ever swap the last digit, with a random digit, and not to mention again that `d` would be out of range`

```
some_ary[x], some_ary[y] = some_ary[y], some_ary[x]
```

Instead lets swap two random positions

And then we can either:

```
results = shuffle(ary, 10)
print(results)
```

or

```
print(f"{shuffle(ary, 10)}")
```

Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: @carlosvelasquez glad to assists! If this solved your problem would appreciate if you checked solved, cheers!